# shapefile for mumbai city areawise or section wise

Tags: maps, geojson, shapefile, qgis

please don't kill me if this question is listed anywhere else, i really searched high and low to find answer to this question.

i am working on a project in which i need to plot data on **Mumbai city map section wise or area wise** but i am not able to get **Shapefile** for the same. can anyone please provide me the link where i can get this Shapefile? or guide me on creating one using **QGIS??**.I mentioned QGIS because i know a little about OGIS and hence it will save time.Also i tried **certain links** which are **listed below**. but i couldn't find what i need.Guys it would be a great help because i really need this  and i am stuck on this from few days.Also i mentioned shapefile because these are easy to manipulate, later i will convert it into geoJSON and work on it so if geoJSON files are there then it would also help.

**Note: only the important links are listed:**
1. http://monsoon.mcgm.gov.in:8080/RESTFulWS/WardMaps.html0
2.http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/

thanks.

Comment: ![this is what i want][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/9Tbc4.png

Comment: ^ image for what i want.